# How Does ExtJS 4 store know to Insert (PUT) or Update (POST) when call store.add(model)?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I open a windows with a form in it and call code as follows:

```
var formWindow = Ext.create('widget.recordform'),   
form = formWindow.down('form').getForm(),       
model = Ext.create('model.record');     
form.loadRecord(model);
formWindow.show();
```

Then, in the save event, when I determine this was a new record and not an update, I call code like this:

```
if (
    var id = store.getTotalCount() + 1;
    record.set("id", id);
    store.add(record);
}
```

The problem is I'm getting a PUT (update) generated through my rest proxy and not a POST (insert).  The doc shows that somehow Ext knows that the record is new (maybe from the Ext.create?) and then knows to make this an insert.

In any case, I'm getting a PUT which means I don't get a new record.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The attribute you're looking for is [`phantom`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-property-phantom). If you want to prevent the record to be phantom, you need to set its [`idProperty`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty) along when you create it:

```
Ext.create('model.record', {
    id: store.getTotalCount() + 1
});
```

(assuming `id` is your `idProperty`, which is the default)

Alternatively, you could also [`commit`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-commit) the record after you've set its `idProperty` and **before** you add it to the store, which should also set the `phantom` flag to false.

Comment: Thanks matt, I'm not quite sure your solution works.  I did find that if I never set the id property that a POST happens as expected.  setting it to anything in my case causes the PUT to happen.  using commit did not seem to have any effect.